# Issue with TypeScript and controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, typescript

So I'm converting a site form `VB` to `C#` and using `TypeScript` in the process. I have it successfully passing the data to the controller, however the controller post back to the same page instead to the next page. 
Here's the `TypeScript` (full module [here](http://pastebin.com/v0b8qMeF))

```
function formSubmission(submitId, submitUrl, formData, validation) {
    if (!submitId || hasSubmit)
        return false;
    if (validation) {
        if (!$("#empApp form").validate().form())
            return false;
        hasSubmit = true;
    }
    hasSubmit = true;
    // add load status functionality
    $(".modal").modal("show");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: submitUrl,
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            window.location.href = "/employment/application/references";
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
            $(".modal-body").html("<h3>" + status + "<small>" + error + "</small></h3>");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".modal").modal("hide");
            }, 100);
            window.location.href = "/employment/application/work-experience";
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the `Controller` ([full here](http://pastebin.com/JBgt1QvN))

```
[HttpPost, Route("Work-Experience")]
public ActionResult WorkExperience(List<EmploymentApplicationWorkExperience> appExperience)
{
    EmploymentApplication empAppSession = getApplication();
    if (!HasSession()) { return InvalidAppSession(); };
    SetupViewBag();
    if (!empAppSession.Steps.HasFlag(EmploymentApplication.ApplicationStepTypes.EducationSkills))
    {
        return PartialView(GetApplicationStepError());
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (appExperience != null)
        {
            empAppSession.ApplicationWorkEperiences = appExperience;
            //  empAppSession.Application.empApWorkExperiences = (ICollection<empApWorkExperience>)appExperience;
            empAppSession.StepCompleted(EmploymentApplication.ApplicationStepTypes.Workexperiences);
            updateApplicationStep(empAppSession.Steps);
            updateApplicationWorkExpriences(empAppSession.ApplicationWorkEperiences);
            updateApplication(empAppSession.Application);
            return RedirectToAction("References");
        }
        return PartialView(GetApplicationView("WorkExperience"), empAppSession.ApplicationWorkEperiences);
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView(GetApplicationView("WorkExperience"), empAppSession.ApplicationWorkEperiences);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to me you need to debug what `submitUrl` is when the function is called. Also unsure what the `typescript` tag has to do with this (?)

Comment: Can't pin point the issue but currently using a typescript file, so wasn't sure if that could be the cause. The `submitUrl` goes to the post attribute method above and intends to return `References`, however, and  haven't figured out where this is triggered, it posts back to the `WorkEperience` view.

Comment: At the end of the day typescript will "compile" to plain javascript (what you have above). That said, check your `View` - and see which "click" invokes `formSubmission` and sends the params (one of which is `submitUrl`)

Answer (score 0):

Used a unnecessary filter on Controller that if not valid, would continue to return the current page. Once removed, page continued with out post back issue.